# Should I stop updating my WordPress page builders?

Tags: wordpress

This may sound like a silly question but I have decided to do a free project for a local church, it’s basically a new website.  I am only going to spend some sort hours on the website  once it’s done,  if I don’t have a chance to update their WordPress or page builders willl they be okay or would they most likely run into a problem? If Nothing is updated in many years would it stop working?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of site you are making. 
If its static site just to display some informations like purposes, contacts, map, and all, then one time setup is ok.
But its regular based sites like updating event dates, information, and all, then it needs to be updated. 
It wont stop working, until its hosting and domain is being paid :)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is free, and it is developed by a community of developers. With each new release, they fix bugs, add new features, improve performance, and enhance existing features to stay up to date with new industry standards.

So in other words, when you do not update your WordPress site, you are risking your website security and missing out on new features / improvements.

when you do not update your WordPress site with latest WordPress your site will not stop it will work on older version.

Answer (score 0):

Once you installed WordPress and added pages in it. Then no need to hesitate when you won't get chance to update your website then WordPress itself Update it's WordPress Version. Also if you are using any Plugin then you can add this code in wp-config.php `add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );` and it will update all plugins automatically and for updating WordPress automatically add this code in wp-config.php `add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_true' );` Also if you don't have time to switch on Laptop or Computer then u can also update blogs, approve comments from mobile using WordPress's Android/iOS App.

Answer (score 0):

By not updating your wordpress site, it would take months or even years before the website starts to have issues.
I have frequently worked on websites where they have not updated their site for years. A lot of the time, we had a lot of problems with these websites; they became unstable and it was hard to predict how they would act to certain changes. 
Keeping a website up to date is a must; the more outdated a website is, the more problems you will encounter.

Rushabhpathak mentions that you should set the website to auto-update. Whilst this sounds good in theory, I would politely have to disagree with this answer. On more than one occasion, I have found that updating a plugin or theme has brought the website offline for whatever reason; whether incompatible or unstable.

If your website is set to update automatically, it may be hard to pinpoint when something goes wrong. I always update my websites manually after taking a backup.
I update each plugin / theme one by one, each time checking that there are no issues. That way, if the website goes down, I can revert my changes easily and know to wait for another update for that particular plugin or theme that won't destroy the website.

My advice to you would be to check the website every month or so, there's no need for you to check everyday or even every week. Your website won't become outdated that quickly so you don't need to worry about the site going down after a few weeks of not updating. As previously mentioned, I've worked on plenty of websites that were forgotten about for years and they still worked (albeit a little rubbish).

Comment: Fully agree with this. I always do updates manually and after a recent back-up. What might be helpful is the use of a service like InfiniteWP to keep monitoring which updates a website has. It's very easy to set-up and can also help you with making back-ups before you do any updates: https://infinitewp.com/